Difference between mean of a function and function of a mean?
I would like to know if it is possible to bound the error between mean of a function and function of a mean i.e. $  \mid \mid \overline{f}(x)-f(\overline{x}) \mid \mid \leq $ ? where $f$ could be any real valued function ranging from polynomials to exponential.
The problem is that we are basically trying to estimate a reaction rate $R(x)$ which is a function of $x$ (which is the length of the catalyst) by simply accounting for the reaction rate at one point at the mid of $x$ so $R(\overline{x})$ implying $R(\overline{x}) \approx 1/L \int_{x=0}^{x=L} R(x) $.  We want to know if we could have error bounds for our estimation i.e.  $\mid \mid R(\overline{x}) - 1/L \int_{x=0}^{x=L} R(x) \mid \mid$ < ? $R \in [a,b]$ where a and b are real numbers ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

This lacks context.  What is the domain of $f$?  Why should there be any connection at all between the mean of $f$ and the mean value in the domain?

Domain could be assumed between any two real numbers i.e. $f \epsilon [a,b]$
